# Avoid vaadin grid automatic horizontal scroll after click

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm using vaadin 8.1 in my project.

I needed to give an extra large width to a grid column (the latest at the right), and when user clicks in one field of this extra large column, vaadin move horizontal scroll automatically at the end of the grid. I would like stop this vaadin behaviour. I researched and I tried different things but I didn't find anything,

How can I do it?

Thank you,

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in Vaadin to turn it off (You can find feature request here: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/7667). There is one trick you could try, namely disable pointer events in Grid cells. It is a bit harsh method, since it will disable also selection and item click.

In your code

```
grid.setStyleGenerator(item -> { return "disable-events";});
```

And your theme

```
 .disable-events {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

It is possible to add the [style generator also for one Column](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.5/8.5.1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setStyleGenerator-com.vaadin.ui.StyleGenerator-) only, which could be option to you as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the way I did and works as I desired :)